# Possible to add data into commands on certain MongoDB collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to add data into commands on certain MongoDB collections?

The use case here is for simple management of multitenancy. We have data that doesn't contain the tenant's id and we then want to insert the tenant's id in on every command (find, update, updateOne, insert, insertMany, etc.) to particular collections (some collections are generic tenant wide collections). We are using the MongoDB driver (rather not use Mongoose).

Currently, we have to remember to add the tenant id whenever we use a command, but this is a bit dangerous as it is possible to miss adding the tenant's id...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we created a helper function which we passed the data to. The helper then adds the tenant's id to any commands nessasay and send the command to MongoDB.

This allows us to control when to restrict by tenant per collection per command type.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Mongo does not come with this feature set.

Mongoose actually shines for these kind of things with its [middleware infrastructure](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

If mongoose is not an option you can look into these smaller `hooks` implementations:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongohooks

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-hooks

They give you something to work with I believe.

Comment: Thanks for this - the NPM modules are a good start for us. 

Yes I realise Mongoose would be a good fit however from our experience the MongoDB native driver + our modifications is a fair amount faster than using Mongoose.

The bits regarding defaults aren't relevant for multitenancy